# perl: thread termination blocked by user input

Tags: multithreading, perl, signals

I have made a program which can terminate in 2 ways, either user enters a string say- "kill" or a specific thread signals SIGINT.

In this terminator thread I have a statement(to catch "kill"):

```
    $a = <>;
```

followed by a 'return;'
I have appropriate signal handler (for INT) too on the top which does:

```
print "signal received\n";
threads->exit();
```

but in the case of automatic termination(that is SIGINT is sent from other thread), the print stmt doesn't come until I press some key, no matter how long I wait. I suppose <> is blocking.

Could someone please tell how can I provide some sort of input to <> in the auto termination case so as to see the results immediately.

Thanks.

Comment: Inside the call to <> your thread has given control to the OS. So, yes, it blocks until   an eof.

Comment: You'll need something other than line-i/o if you want to break in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're trying to do, the way you're trying to do it. If a file is being read, and 'pending input' then process goes into an uninterruptible wait state. You basically can't interrupt it via signalling at this point. Uninterruptible waits are a kernel thing and the key point is preventing file corruption.

To do what you're trying to do, you would probably need to make use of something like [`IO::Select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) and the `can_read` function. You can test which filehandles are ready for IO, in a polling loop - this polling loop *is* interruptible by kill signals.

Alternatively, instead of using a filehandle read, you can use [`Term::ReadKey`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TermReadKey/ReadKey.pm) which will allow you to trap a keypress in a nonblocking fashion